# Abrindo HTML dentro de uma DIV, não recupera os paramentos via GET

Tags: jquery, html5

estou usando o Jquery para carregar uma pagina HTML dentro de uma `<div>`. Meu código está funcionando corretamente, porém ele não está passando um valor via GET que eu preciso na outra página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Exemplo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>    
 <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a onclick="carregar('receita.html?cod=1')" href="#">Receita 1</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="carregar('receita.html?cod=2')" href="#">Receita 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
</body>
<script>
    function carregar(pagina){
        $("#conteudo").load(pagina);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Estou usando uma função na pagina `receita.html` que recupera a variável `cod`

Então, se eu abrir no navegador `receita.html?cod=10` ele recupera essa variável, mas abrindo o conteúdo dentro da `<div>` ele até abre a pagina, mas não recupera o `cod`.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver isso?

Comment: o javascript está correto, o problema parece estar em `receita.html`, você pode adicionar a parte desse arquivo onde você utiliza a variável GET? Tente adicionar `var_dump($_GET);exit;` no inicio do arquivo para ver o que aparece

Comment: Fiz isso mas não aconteceu nada, 
Eu estou recuperando assim:

`function getUrlVars(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
var var_cod = getUrlVars()["cod"];`

Se eu abrir a pagina receita.html no meu navegador funciona... somente dentro da div que não

Comment: identifiquei o problema, você está buscando as variáveis GET com javascript em `receita.html`, mas quando você chama a página com `.load('receita.html')`, o javascript da página **não são executados**

Comment: Isso mesmo... e não sei como carrega-los.
Talvez a solução seria colocar essas variáveis em campos do tipo `hidden` e na hora que carregar essa pagina puxar os valores desses campos

Answer (score 1):

Percebi que você está tentando obter um valor que você já tem (`cod` está no atributo `onclick`). Esses valores podem ser acessíveis em javascript através dos atributos `data-*` onde `*` pode ser substituído por um nome.

Como você já está utilizando jQuery, é melhor usar a função [`.on('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) do que o atributo `onclick`.

jQuery tem a função [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) que acessa os valores do atributos `data-*` diretamente.

```js
$('#sidebar a').on('click', function() {
  // this se refere ao <a> clicado
  var cod = $(this).data('cod'); // acesse sem o prefixo "data-"
  $("#conteudo").html('"cod" é igual a ' + cod);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <a data-cod="1" href="#">Receita 1</a><!-- observe data-cod="1" -->
  <a data-cod="2" href="#">Receita 2</a>
</div>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```